# How to create a rectangular svg grid as texture on a three.js mesh

Tags: javascript, svg, three.js

How to create a rectangular svg grid as textur on a three.js mesh? The mesh can have a dynamic size. I want the svg texture not to be stretched, and to keep its original size.

The result should look like on this picture]

[image].

Here's a jsfiddle from my current status: https://jsfiddle.net/s7vjkLon/6/

As you can see the SVG (top-left) has a size of 128px and on the mesh (bottom) the SVG is not shown in its original size. It´s stretched.

```js
function init() {

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.setClearColor(0xFFFFFF);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.z = 500;

 scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.add(camera);

}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function createGridOnMesh(options) {

 var space = options.space;
  var meshWidth = options.meshWidth;
  var meshHeight = options.meshHeight;
  var lineWidth = 2;

  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  canvas.width = Math.pow(2, 7);
  canvas.height = Math.pow(2, 7);

  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  context.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0)";
  context.fillRect(Math.round(lineWidth / 2), Math.round(lineWidth / 2), canvas.width - lineWidth, canvas.height - lineWidth);

  var texture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvas);
  texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  texture.repeat.set(2, 2);   
  texture.needsUpdate = true;
  
  geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(meshWidth, meshHeight, 200);
  material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  scene.add( mesh );  

}


init();
animate();
createGridOnMesh({ space: 20, meshWidth: 600, meshHeight: 200})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/101/three.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Drawing a rectangular grid seems trivial enough that you can just generate it with an HTML canvas (or fill in a Uint8Array) and use that as a texture.

Comment: Take a look at this [forum topic](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-achieve-this-material-effect-gif-image/1270?u=prisoner849).

Comment: Thanks @prisoner849 for the very interesting approach. I find the shader usage very interesting, but i am a newcomer in this field. Therefore i would prefer an approach with svg texture.

Comment: @PeterO. : Drawing a rectangular grid is really trivial. but I don't always have the mesh size. The mesh is also not always rectangular. So I thought about drawing only one grid tile in svg and then mapping it.

But why is the rectangular grid tile no longer rectangular after mapping?